# Angular ResolveFn is not assignable to type 'ResolveFn<Observable>

Tags: angular

I'm following a tutorial about a CRUD application using Angular, Java and Spring. Right now I'm implementing this resolver in order to add the logic to the "edit" button on the CRUD. The CRUD is about sales, so I have interfaces of client, product and sales where I have an id, client and products.

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ResolveFn, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Sale } from '../model/sales';
import { SalesService } from '../services/sales.service';



export const saleResolver: ResolveFn<Observable<Sale>> = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot,  service: SalesService = inject(SalesService)) => {
  if (route.params?.['id']){
    return service.loadById(route.params['id']);
  }
  return of(
    {
      sale: [],
    }
    )
};
```

My error occurs in the line

```js
export const saleResolver: ResolveFn<Observable<Sale>> = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:
```

Where it says that

```
Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot, service?: SalesService) => void | Observable<{ sale: never[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'ResolveFn<Observable<Sale>>'.
  Type 'void | Observable<{ sale: never[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Sale> | Observable<Observable<Sale>> | Promise<Observable<Sale>>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Sale> | Observable<Observable<Sale>> | Promise<Observable<Sale>>'.ts(2322)
```

In the tutorial the return of was using the attributes from the interface like (id: ' ', name: ' '), but I can't do that because my attributes aren't strings, they're objects and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Some questions here. Where does the 'void' come from? service.loadById has to return an Observable<Sale> to fit. Does your Sale object really consist of a sale attribute which is an array? To explicitly return a Sale object you could write of({ sale: [] } as Sale);

Comment: my sale Object consist of three attributes, an id which is a string, a Client and a Product:
`
export interface Sale {
  _id: string;
  client: Client;
  product: Product;
}
`
i'm actually not sure about where the void come from, i didn't manage to understand this error very well to be honest :p

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty simple to understand. The TypeScript parser takes the return types from any control path and concatenates different ones using |.
So one of your control paths returns void, the other an Observable. As the latter obviously comes from `return of(...);` the void must be the result of `return service.findById(...);`. **Please check whether the result of `SalesService.findById` really is an Observable.**

This one works for me:

```
export const resolver: ResolveFn<Observable<Sale>> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  service = inject(SalesService)
) => {
  if (route.params?.['id']) {
    return service.findById(route.params?.['id']);
  }
  return of({} as Sale);
};
```

with SalesService.findById

```
findById(id: number) : Observable<Sale> {
   ...
}
```